# ¿Cómo refresco para que se reflejen los cambios después de crear un inicio de sesión SQLServer mediante código VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

El usuario se crea correctamente porque si cierro el programa y lo vuelvo a ejecutar, se ejecuta correctamente, pero si creo el usuario y reintento no detecta que el usuario ya existe, me supongo que ocurre porque aunque se crea el objeto, la base no se refresca y no se reflejan los cambios. Qué línea añado para que se reflejen los cambios. El código que crea el usuario termina en:

```
      ComandoCrearSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
      ComandoRol1SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
      ComandoRol2SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Me supongo que después de eso hay que añadir una línea para que se refresque la base y se reflejen los cambios. ¿Qué añado?